# Checkbox checked works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Message sending form, the customer has to select at least one of the alternatives (mail, SMS).

Send button would be disabled if none is selected and activate if one or both selected

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-input').change(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Epost" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="E-post">E-post</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="SMS">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="SMS">SMS</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.form-check-input').change(function() {
  $("#send").prop("disabled", ($('.form-check-input:checked').length == 0 ? true : false));
});
```

This will disable the button if none of the checkbox are checked.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-input').change(function() {
    $("#send").prop("disabled", ($('.form-check-input:checked').length == 0 ? true : false));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Epost" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="E-post">
                        E-post
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="SMS">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="SMS">
                        SMS
                    </label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because your current logic does not deal with checkboxes being re-checked.

You can solve the problem by inverting the logic so that the `disabled` property is updated on every checkbox change, and is determined by the `length` of the checked boxes:

```js
var $checkboxes = $('.form-check-input').change(function() {
  $('#send').prop('disabled', function() {
    return $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == 0;
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Epost" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="E-post">E-post</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="SMS">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="SMS">SMS</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never enable the button again. There is just a disable instruction.

I would disable it by default at beginning and then enable it if any of the checkboxes is checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-input').change(function() {
    $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(this).each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#send").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Epost" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="E-post">E-post</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="SMS">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="SMS">SMS</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-input').change(function() {
    let hasChecked = false;
    $('.form-check-input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        hasChecked = true;
      }
    });
    $("#send").attr("disabled", !hasChecked);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Epost" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="E-post">E-post</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="SMS">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="SMS">SMS</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your logic. Once disabled you are not enabling again when checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-input').change(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
      }else{
        $("#send").attr("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  });
});

Blockquote
```